# XSLT select node where value of nodeset matches several string

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Let this be the xml:

```
... some other parent elements here ...
<subject group="a">Economy</subject>
<subject group="b">Math</subject>
<subject group="a">Finance</subject>
<subject group="c">Arts</subject>
... some other elements here
```

I would like to process and print a heading where group 'a' and 'b' is under one heading, and c is in another heading. 'C' is not a definite string, it can be 'd', 'd'. I just want to  seperate 'a' and 'b',  from anything else.  So an example output would be

Main Subjects (a and b)

- Economy Finance Math

Others

- Arts

Now, I have this code for the "Others" part:

```
<xsl:if test="not(subject/@group[. = 'a'] or subject/@group[. = 'b])">
                <h2>Others</h2> 
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="subject">      
                        <xsl:sort select="./@group"/>
                        <xsl:if test="@group!='a'and @type!='b'">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
</xsl:if>
```

This doesn't work properly. I've tried without the not() and with !=

In short i just want to know if there is any element besides those of group a and b. If there is, print something, if there isn't anything, don't print out the heading "Others".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h2>Main Subjects</h2>
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="//subject[@group/.='a' or @group/.='b']">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    <h2>Others</h2>
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="//subject[not(@group/.='a' or @group/.='b')]">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:** `@group/.='a'` or `@group ='a'` both are fine,

Comment: Why specify **@group/.='a'** and not simply **@group='a'** ?

Comment: @Maestro13, Both are fine, actually I didn't test this code, just typed .. so went on typing without lookin back :P

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes because I don't want <h2>Others</h2> to be printed when there are no subjects that doesn't belong to a and b. So I added an if on top of the others using your selector. I'm still not sure I understand the selector itself though. Could you explain? Let's say group is 'c', it is false for (@group/.='a' or @group/.='b'), then 'not(false)' =  true. so select subject[true] ?

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="//subject[not(@group/.='a' or @group/.='b')]">` copies all other subjects having @group other than 'a' and 'b', you can take whole `for-each` block off, if you don't want them to be printed ..